# Automatic rendering of changes made in code using Volumes concept (node app running in Docker VM)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Now the changes made in .Jade files are rendered automatically on web UI, however the code changes made in node.js files are not rendering, so far, here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
 www:
 build: .
 volumes: 
  - ./:/app_ww
 ports:
  - "80:3000"
 expose: 
  - "80"
```

and here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:4.4.1

RUN mkdir -p app_ww

WORKDIR /app_ww

ADD package.json package.json

RUN npm install

ADD . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I am not getting my required work done. i.e, 
automatic rendering of change made in code. so, here is the list of volumes created in the system by building the repository via `$docker-compose up --build` :

```
$ docker volume ls

DRIVER VOLUME NAME
local  app_ww
```

Package.JsOn file :

```
{
  "name": "node_restapi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "less-middleware": "~2.1.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

NOTE: The container is running fine but the concept of volumes is not working, 
ISSUE: Mentioned in the subject above.

Comment: Why have you created another question that duplicates your previous one?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding volumes. The volume path is the path _INSIDE_ the container that you want to live outside of the docker layered filesystem.

Comment: Need to put the question along with .yml and dockerfile so did again. 
However Let me explain the situation:
I am using ubuntu 14.04 , then i have virtualBox running ubuntu VM image, and i have mounted my code repositories from ubuntu 14.04 to VM. 
Now i need to run a server for a web app in node/express, obviously i have docker-compose.yml file and dockerfile in place to run the server. 
server is working fine, 
WHat i wanted is that whenever i make changes in my source code, i do not want to manually stop the server container and restart it again to take effect of changes made in code so far

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. Tell us 1) what directory does your code live in on your host. 2) what directory do you want it to live in inside your container.

Comment: What `npm start` does? Can you paste your package.json in your question?

Comment: Hi, JHarris:- my code live in repository (absolute path) `/home/vagrant/my_repos/node_restapi`  , 
inside my container it could be anything, lets say it is `/app_ww`

hi ShanShan, i've posted my package.json file in question.
Regards.

Comment: I have done some progress so far, the container is running by `$ docker-compose up --build` now the progress is all the changes made on .Jade files are updating on UI, while the back-end node.js files are not .   *** what i have done is just added two lines in my Dockerfile, `RUN mkdir -p app_ww` and `WORKDIR /app_ww` . also i have replaced volume: part in  my docker-compose.yml by this one line only:- `volume:  -./:/app_ww `............. it is working fine, except for the node files rendering. 
Any help would be appreciated.
**I have updated my files in Question as well**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for the problem i was facing.
Here it is ,

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Including nodemon in the docker file with -g (globally) flag , works perfectly for me.
Thankyou @JHarris, @Aditya, @ShanShan

Regards,
Muhammad Abubaker

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker-machine, I suppose the volume is mounted from the "machine" you create and not the native file system. You have to jump through a couple of hoops to have a native fs directory mounted to the docker-machine instance. What OS are you on? This seems to be logged as an intermittent issue here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2247

Comment: I've discussed it above , however i am writing it here as well: 

 I am using ubuntu 14.04 , then i have virtualBox running ubuntu VM image, and i have mounted my code repositories from ubuntu 14.04 to VM. Now i need to run a server for a web app in node/express, obviously i have docker-compose.yml file and dockerfile in place to run the server. server is working fine, WHat i wanted is that whenever i make changes in my source code, i do not want to manually stop the server container and restart it again to take effect of changes made in code so far